# Redux state undefined on function but not on render()

Tags: react-native, redux, parse-server

Im using redux and i want to render my main drawer based if an user is logged on or not. I have this 'init' class that will check for that and do it accordingly.

I'll post the code and explain it at the end:

**Init.js**

```
const mapStateToProps = (userReducer) => {
  return {
    ...userReducer,
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    dispatch,
    getCurrentUser: () => {
      dispatch(getCurrentUser())
    }
  }
}

class Init extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.props.getCurrentUser()

    console.log("TEST>>")
    console.log(this.props)
}

  chooseInitialRoute() {
    const { navigation, user } = this.props;
    if (user) {
      navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset(
        { index: 0, key: null, actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'LoggedDrawer' })] }
      ))
    } else {
      navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset(
        { index: 0, key: null, actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'UnloggedDrawer' })] }
      ))
    }
  }
```

**user_actions.js**

```
export function getCurrentUser() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    Parse.User.currentAsync().then(function (user) {
      if (user) {
        dispatch({ type: 'GET_USER', payload: { user } })
      } else {
        dispatch({ type: 'GET_USER_REJECTED', payload: error })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

The **console.log(this.props)** returns undefined if called inside the constructor (same happens when I do **console.log(props)**. But if I call it inside render() I get the props correcly (meaning that I get the correct user object from parse server).

Is there any way to update the props before the render() method? I want to get the 'updated' props on the **chooseInitialRoute()**

Thanks in advance. If more code is needed let me know.

Comment: Can you show all the init.js code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `console.log(props)` is undefined in the constructor this means the component later gets the props via componentWillReceiveProps and i dont know where you call InitialRoute but you might consider putting it in the lifecycle function instead:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    const { navigation, user } = props;
    if (user) {
      navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset(
        { index: 0, key: null, actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'LoggedDrawer' })] }
      ))
    } else {
      navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset(
        { index: 0, key: null, actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'UnloggedDrawer' })] }
      ))
    }
}
```

Note that if your props are undefined in the constructor then your component may render multiple times before your component finally receives props via componentWillReceiveProps.